# How do I stop alertManager alerts when a job, "kured reboot", is running?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, reboot, prometheus-alertmanager

When nodes reboot based on the job "kured_reboots", alertManager still alerts on other node alerts. Is there a way to stop alertManager alerts for nodes going through a reboot based on the job "kured_reboot'? Something like this:

```
route:
  receiver: default
  group_by:
  - cluster
  - namespace
  - severity
  - alertname
  - job
  continue: false
  routes:
  - receiver: receiver1
    matchers:
    - job =~ "kured_reboot"
    active_time_intervals:
    - business-hours
  inhibit_rules:
  - source_matchers:
  - job="kured_reboot"
  target_matchers:
  - severity=~"critical|warning|info"
  equal:
  - namespace
  - alertname
```

So far, I am still researching this and have not tried anything yet. I wanted to ask if anyone has done something like this before.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there are two way to do it:

1. Incorporate additional check about this job into your alert rules. For this you'll need to add something like `unless on() my_job_status{name="kured_reboot"} == 1` (You might need to something similar or even completely different depending on your situation and style of job and metrics related to it)
2. Create alert based on the fact that this job is running and add the [inhibition rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#inhibit_rule), that will prevent other alert from firing while job is running.